How to list saved playlists for an authorized user with no channel using YouTube Data API?
I'm trying to list all playlists related to an authorized user account using YouTube Data API. I'm able to successfully fetch required playlists for user account which have an associated channel. However YouTube Data API fails to return playlists for user account without an associated channel.
URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&mine=true&maxResults=50
Response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Channel not found.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Channel not found.",
                "domain": "youtube.playlist",
                "reason": "channelNotFound",
                "location": "channelId",
                "locationType": "parameter"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Is it possible to return list of all playlists saved by a user account with no associated channel through YouTube Data API or any other programmable way?

The YouTube Data API is channel based. This means when a user authorizes your application they must pick the channel they wish to grant your application access to.
You will only have access to that channel.
There for if a user does have an account with out a channel associated to it you will not be able to access it via the api.
Remember this is a very old api which has not been updated in years it may not support all the features you want.

This is clearly a bug in the YouTube Data API.
The documentation clearly states an authorized lists playlist request with mine=true should return all playlist's for a user. There's no documented requirement that the user must have a channel.
As you've already discovered, you can work around the issue by creating a channel for the user. Then the API works as documented
I've opened a bug in Google's issue tracker.
